# Oracle - SQL Join 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables. One to keep data about Person, other to keep data about employee, and other to keep data about tasks the employee did.

Like this

```
Person 

    (id_person, name, ...)

Employee

(id_employee, id_person, ...)

Task

(id_task, id_employee, id_supervisor, id_supervisor_boss)
```

The columns **id_employee, id_supervisor, id_supervisor_boss** are all mapped to the **Employee.id_employee**

How can I get the name of those 3?

Doing something like

```
SELECT P.name 
FROM task T
JOIN Employee E on (T.id_employee = E.id_employee)
JOIN Person P on (E.id_person = P.id_person)
where T.id_task = 1;
```

will only bring the name of one (the guy who did the task), but I need the supervisor and supervisor_boss

Comment: for doing that i think you should have a supervisor table, don't you?

Comment: No, because supervisor IS an employee. So is 'supervisor_boss'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the `Employee` and `Person` tables once for each type: Employee, Supervisor, and Supervisor Boss. This can be done by aliasing the tables:

```
SELECT
  EmpPerson.Name,
  SupPerson.Name,
  BossPerson.Name
FROM Task T
INNER JOIN Employee EmpEmp ON T.ID_Employee = EmpEmp.ID_Employee)
INNER JOIN Person EmpPerson ON EmpEmp.ID_Person = EmpPerson.ID_Person
INNER JOIN Employee SupEmp ON T.ID_Supervisor = SupEmp.ID_Employee
INNER JOIN Person SupPerson ON SupEmp.ID_Person = SupPerson.ID_Person
INNER JOIN Employee BossEmp ON T.ID_Supervisor_Boss = BossEmp.ID_Employee
INNER JOIN Person BossPerson ON BossEmp.ID_Person = BossPerson.ID_Person
```

Comment: It's all those joins that I was trying to avoid. Is there another way for doing that without a SQL so wordy?

Comment: The only shorter way I can think of would be to write a PL/SQL function that takes an employee ID and returns the name, but user-defined functions can really slow down your query.

Answer (score 2):

you need to go to join to the employee and person tables three times (employee/supervisor/boss).
Here's one solution:

```
           select e.name employee_name, e_s.name supervisor_name, e_sb.name supervisor_boss_name 
            from task t, 
                 employee e_e, employee e_s, employee e_sb, 
                 person e, person s, person sb
            where  t.id_employee = e_e.id_employee
            and e_e.person_id  e.person_id
            and t.id_supervisor = e_s.id_employee
            and e_s.person_id = s.person_id
            and t.id_supervisor_boss = e_sb.id_employee
            and e_sb.person_id = sb.person_id
            and t.id_task = 1;
```